# Different width/weight when creating Android layout programmatically vs. in XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create Buttons that have the same width and are stretched to (match) the parent. I need to do it *programmatically*. First I created a layout draft of desired state (focus just on the ***green line*** of buttons):

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/greenLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/button_bottom_padding">

        <!-- This vertical LinearLayout with Button repeats 5x (Each Button has different text and ID) -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_left_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/button_right_padding">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:text="O"
                style="@style/green_button" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- 4 more time -->

    </LinearLayout>
```

And then I decomposed the draft into **vertical** `LinearLayout` and separate green `Button`. In the main layout there is just **horizontal greenLine** `LinearLayout`:

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/greenLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/button_bottom_padding">

    </LinearLayout>
```

**linear_layout_vertical.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_left_padding"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/button_right_padding"></LinearLayout>
```

**green_button.xml**

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/green_button" />
```

Green Button style:

```
<style name="button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">0</item>
</style>

<style name="green_button" parent="button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/green_button_state</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/green_button</item>
</style>
```

After that I get this:

[image]

These are the functions I use to create green line of Buttons:

```
private void _createGreenLine() {

    // Possible values for green line
    String[] values = {"O", "N", "S", "M", "C"};

    for (String value: values) {
        // Layout container
        LinearLayout linearLayout = this._createLinearLayout();
        // Button
        Button button = (Button) this.getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.green_button, null);
        button.setText(value);
        // Button to layout
        linearLayout.addView(button);

        // Layout to green line
        this.greenLine.addView(linearLayout);
    }
}

private LinearLayout _createLinearLayout() {

    return (LinearLayout) this.getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.linear_layout_vertical, null);
}
```

I also tried to change the addition of new Views (I added `linearLayout` first, call `getChildAt` on greenLine and added `Button` at last).

Thanks a lot in advance.

**SOLUTION: CHANGES MADE FOR LAYOUT TO BE DISPLAYED PROPERLY**

```
private LinearLayout _createLinearLayout(ViewGroup root) {

    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) this.getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.linear_layout_vertical, root, false);
    return linearLayout;
}
```

And

```
Button button = (Button) this.getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.green_button, (ViewGroup) linearLayout, false);
```

Read more: <[Layout Inflation as Intended](http://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/)>

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but you need to set `layout_weight` of each `Button` to an equal value (example 1) and set `layout_width` to be `0dp` - the buttons will then be equally sized and equally spread.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've tried to change Buttons the way you wrote but no XML Buttons have been shown. I've also changed `layout_weight` to different number. But this experiment has shown me another (good) thing though :)...None of the buttons were shown except the green ones. That might mean the programmatically created Buttons are not affected by the style after inflation at all...

Comment: There's another complication. If you look at your first XML layout file (the one below the screenshot of green and red lines), why do you have an outer `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation but then have an inner `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation where you place the green buttons? If you want your green buttons spread horizontally then they should be in a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation.

Comment: Well this is just a first stage, later, vertical LinearLayout will hold more Views than one Button. That's why I need extra container. Sorry for confusing you but I want to provide as much information as need :) Still the question is why layout created in XML is different than the one programmed. Looks like something gets "lost" during programming, or inflating.

Comment: OK, I think I understand you now. You want vertical `LinearLayout` "columns" containing more than one button but you want the "columns" arranged horizontally (as you'd expect with columns). In that case change `linear_layout_vertical.xml` so the `layout_width` of the `LinearLayout` is `0dp`.

Comment: Did you try using the second parameter of inflate() method?

Comment: @Squonk - I changed the `linear_layout_vertical.xml` to `layout_width=0dp` and `layout_weight=1`, but it is not stretched, looks same as at the 2nd picture I've posted.

Comment: @pskink Second parameter? `root - Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy.` - use when adding Button to layout?

Comment: Yes, did you try that?

Comment: @pskink, Thank you very much! I've googled the second parameter's meaning and usage and found this article http://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/. It provides information how to use inflation properly. If null as second parameter is used, styles are not copied from XML correctly. Please, add you "second parameter" as answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling `parent.addView(child)` you should use the second parameter of `inflate()` method